# Using document.createRange and window.getSelection in React

Tags: reactjs

I am using Reactjs. In react how to use `document.createRange` and `window.getSelection` as well as `document.execCommand('copy')` in React ?

I want to copy the contents of my html table . So I used the code

```
copyTable(e){
        let elTable = this.tableElement.current.localName\\ elTable= "table"     
  this.copyData(elTable)
    }

    copyData(elToBeCopied){

        let range, sel;

  // Ensure that range and selection are supported by the browsers
  if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {

    range = document.createRange();
    sel = window.getSelection();
    // unselect any element in the page
    sel.removeAllRanges();

    try {
      range.selectNodeContents(elToBeCopied);
      sel.addRange(range);
    } catch (e) {
      range.selectNode(elToBeCopied);
      sel.addRange(range);
    }

    document.execCommand('copy');
  }

  sel.removeAllRanges();

  console.log('Element Copied! Paste it in a file')


    }
```

I got the value of `elTable` by creating a `ref` in my html table.

When debugged the debugger is entering into the function  `copyData` .

But can't copy data from table. Why?

I am using react js.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me in a CRA project.  Where are you using react?  Node? C# Web App?

Comment: Using Reactjs .

Comment: When I debugged `range = document.createRange();` , after `document` there is no `createRange()`

Answer (score 0):

Using the following in App.js `render() method`:

```
console.log(window.getSelection());
console.log(document.createRange());
```

Gives results in the console:

[image]

Have you tried using them at all?  Might be helpful if you show your code where this isn't working and we can go from there.

Comment: I got the results in console. I edited question with code. I am not able to copy the contents from my html table